# umbraco install pains

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco

```
Error reading XSLT file: \xslt\umbTopNavigation.xslt
```

i've tried installing on more than one server  -everyone has permissions to install a kitchen sink if they wish - not going away.

I'd have expected the install for this to be a bit smoother to be honest.

anyone?

Comment: I suspect this is a "file not found", not an "access denied". Get [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), let it log all filesystem access during the install and search for `umbTopNavigation.xslt` to see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cause of this is that you dared to change the XSLT on disk.

Open it up in the Umbraco ui, save it, and you should be good

also: razor kicks xslt's rear end. just sayin'

:)

[edit]
like @Tomalak said, is the file actually there? is it a valid xslt file? anything in umbLog table? what happens if you remove that from the template?

Comment: this is a completely fresh isntall. no alterations nuffink. also - how can i switch it to razor? xslt is for goons

Comment: use 4.7.x. Razor stuff is under developer -> scripting files. Works like a macro from in the template.

Comment: i don't think you _get_ how messed up this install is :) http://parrparr.net/umbraco

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't install umbraco in a folder. It has to be root (unless there is a config option for it)

Comment: there is in the wizzard (i fekin hate wizards)

Comment: yeah - can't handle sub folders... hmmmmmmm

Answer (score 3):

Copy the file Web/xlst/umbTopNavigation.xlst to /xlst/umbTopNavigation.xlst.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to copy the file from `/Umbraco/xlst/umbTopNavigation.xlst` to `/xls/umbTopNavigation.xlst` as pointed out by @BlackjacketMack.

However the problem of why "umbraco install [can be a] pain" is that at the beginning, you probably ran the  starterKit when the application path was `/umbraco` most likely defaulted by Visual Studio.

If you then change this to use `/` as the application path, all will mess up and the only solution is to move them back to the root again.